# How to set a default camera with android using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app, the user needs to send two photos, one with a back camera and one with front, the code that I'm using only opens the back camera with a option of switching cameras, but I want to lock to only use on or other depending the scenario.

This is how I'm doing

```
 private fun openCamera() {
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture")
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From the Camera")
    image_uri = requireContext().contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
    //camera intent
    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to lock to only use on or other depending the scenario.

That is not an option with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

If you need that degree of control, you will need to implement image capture within your own app, rather than delegating to an external app as you are doing with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. You could use the camera APIs directly, though it is simpler to use a wrapper library (Google's CameraX or [various third-party libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/141?sort=created)).